# Java: Calling a parent's method with child's member variable

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, member-variables

Let's say I have an abstract parent class that has member variables which are used in a method.

```
public abstract class Person{
    public String jobTitle;
    public void printJob(){
        System.out.println(jobTitle);
    }
}
```

If I now have two child classes

```
public class Teacher extends Person{
    public String jobTitle = "Teacher";
}
public class Janitor extends Person{
    public String jobTitle = "Janitor";
}
```

and I want to avoid code cloning, i.e. implementing the same printJob()-method in both classes, I now have a problem, since the printJob()-method is unable to access member variables of the child classes.

Is there any way that i can call a parent classes' method but have the method use the child classes' member variables?

Comment: Look up "abstract methods" or "calling parent constructors"

Comment: You must implement a setter for the variable jobTitle in the abstract class Person. In Teacher / Janitor you call the setter with the corresponding value and then you can call the method printJob().

Comment: Also, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 2):

You can use abstract methods like this

```
public abstract class Person {
   public void printJob() {
      System.out.println(getJobTitle());
   }

   protected abstract String getJobTitle();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Person teacher = new Teacher();
      Person janitor = new Janitor();

      System.out.println(teacher.getJobTitle());
      System.out.println(janitor.getJobTitle());
   }
}

class Teacher extends Person {
   @Override
   protected String getJobTitle() {
      return "Teacher";
   }
}

class Janitor extends Person {
   @Override
   protected String getJobTitle() {
      return "Janitor";
   }
}
```

Updated after op's comment for code cloning...

```
public class Person {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(new Teacher().job);
      System.out.println(new Janitor().job);
   }

   private static class Teacher extends Person {
      private String job = "Teacher";
   }

   private static class Janitor extends Person {
      private String job = "Janitor";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this brings back my original problem in which I have cloned code because the getJobTitle method is the same in both classes.

Comment: if you don't care that much for code quality, see my updated answer..